# AndroidResideMenu Custom Layout

Tags: android, residemenu

I am using  [AndroidResideMenu](https://github.com/SpecialCyCi/AndroidResideMenu) library .

But what I need to add is a Menu with a profile picture at the bottom ..

How do I add a custom view to the Reside Menu to achieve that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I jut hooked up the project and the default view that renders in the demo cannot be modified (because it was included as a maven repository). However you can include the source files in your project and access the layout files from there.

[image]

You need to include ResideMenu in your current project (possibly manually, and remember to keep in mind the licensing rights).

The file you want to add your ImageView to is:
https://github.com/SpecialCyCi/AndroidResideMenu/blob/master/ResideMenu/res/layout/residemenu_custom_left_scrollview.xml

which belongs to the ResideMenu library.
This issue is related to:
[how to access resources in a android library project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053141/how-to-access-resources-in-a-android-library-project)

Hope this was useful.