# How to access to android library own resources

Tags: android, resources, android-resources, android-library, android-context

I'm developing an Android Library that has strings and layout resources.

How can I get them without creating an Activity class?

I don't want to access to "main project" resources, I read a lot of questions about that :P, I'm in a "plain class" inside the module and I need the module resources.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421244/accessing-application-resources-from-the-library-project

Comment: @MarcoAcierno Well... that's exactly that I DON'T need to do, this question talks about how library can access application resources, I need that library access their own resources. Also I don't know how to get Context, I don't want the application context, I need the library context

Answer (score 2):

I was able to accomplish this by addressing the resources as you normally would, from **inside** of my library, to create a reusable custom dialog:

`customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog, container, false);`

The catch here seems to be how you build/import this library. I think that by default, marking the project as a library packages it up as a `jar` file. However, I was able to get at these resources by packaging as Android Application Resource (`aar`) file. If you compare the structures of these files, you'll see that an `aar` will have everything under your `res/` direcotry, rather than just the class files (as in a `jar`).

I'm using maven, so I used built my package like this:

```
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>my-library</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>aar</packaging>
<name>My Library</name>
```

Then, when importing my library into my project, I made sure to specify the `type`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-library</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
```

This is possible with Gradle as well - you can specify `aar` as your archive type if necessary:

```
compile 'my.company:my-library:1.0-SNAPSHOT@aar'
```