# Is it possible to redefine a library's databinding resource?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater, android-databinding

I am developing a library that uses Data Binding to process attributes in a `Layout`'s `Views` (I won't develop as it is irrelevant to this issue).

As the applications should be able to specify their own layout, I am trying to leverage the [resource prioritization mechanism](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryModules):

> In cases where a resource ID is defined in both the application and
>   the library, the tools ensure that the resource declared in the
>   application gets priority and that the resource in the library module
>   is not compiled into the application `apk`.   This gives your
>   application the flexibility to either use or redefine any resource
>   behaviors or values that are defined in any library.

This works fine as long as the application's layout contains **exactly as many** views than the library's. However, when I add more views to the application's layout, the following exception happens at runtime when inflating the layout:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.plnech.example, PID: 31773
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
at android.databinding.ViewDataBinding.mapBindings(ViewDataBinding.java:938)
at android.databinding.ViewDataBinding.mapBindings(ViewDataBinding.java:995)
at android.databinding.ViewDataBinding.mapBindings(ViewDataBinding.java:568)
at com.plnech.library.databinding.HitsItemBinding.<init>(HitsItemBinding.java:23)
at com.plnech.library.databinding.HitsItemBinding.bind(HitsItemBinding.java:102)
at android.databinding.DataBinderMapper.getDataBinder(DataBinderMapper.java:11)
at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.bind(DataBindingUtil.java:185)
at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:120)
at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:88)
at com.plnech.library.helper.databinding.ResultsAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(ResultsAdapter.java:36)
at com.plnech.library.helper.databinding.ResultsAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(ResultsAdapter.java:21)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5482)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4707)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1994)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1390)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1353)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3028)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2625)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:676)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:479)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback
```

It seems that as the library's layout has only 1 item, the generated bindings are stored in a array of length=1, and then accessed at index 2 as the application's layout has 2 items. But if the prioritization is done at compile-time, shouldn't the bindings be generated with the application's layout?

Likewise, when the application's layout has **less** Views than the library's, I get this exception when inflating the layout:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.plnech.example, PID: 14269
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTag(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
at com.plnech.library.databinding.HitsItemBinding.<init>(HitsItemBinding.java:31)
at com.plnech.library.databinding.HitsItemBinding.bind(HitsItemBinding.java:118)
at android.databinding.DataBinderMapper.getDataBinder(DataBinderMapper.java:11)
at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.bind(DataBindingUtil.java:185)
at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:120)
at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:88)
at com.plnech.library.helper.databinding.ResultsAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(ResultsAdapter.java:36)
at com.plnech.library.helper.databinding.ResultsAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(ResultsAdapter.java:21)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5482)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4707)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1994)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1390)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1353)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3028)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2625)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:676)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:479)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
```

### Is there a way to use data binding and still allow an application to redefine a bound resource with a different amount of Views?

Comment: I had the same issue. Did you fix it?

Comment: @CaferMertCeyhan I'm afraid no ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I started to use our old friend findViewById and fixed it. I deleted layout  tag for the layout.