# Not able to access image in drawable from non-activity class in Android

Tags: android, drawable, android-context

I have created an Android library project that i am linking with my Android app. In the drawable folder of the library project, I have added a few images. Now I am trying to access these images from a non-activity class in the same project but they are not being accessed when I try to access them using the following snippet

```
Drawable drawable=context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image);
```

The import of R file is correct and the image id is being generated correctly in the R file. The context is correct. I tried refreshing and cleaning/building the project multiple times but nothing seems to work.

Help!

Comment: how is the `context` obtained?

Answer (score 0):

[**Note**: Answer copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421244/accessing-application-resources-from-the-library-project/9421473#9421473).]

Yes you can if you know the package name of your library.
[Resources.getIdentifier(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

You can do:

`getResources().getIdentifier("res_name", "res_type", "com.library.package");`

ex:

`R.id.settings` would be:

`getResources().getIdentifier("settings", "id", "com.library.package");`

Comment: This returns an id. I need a drawable. How do I make the conversion? And why exactly is this happening anyway?

Comment: The identifier is the one you use instead of `R.drawable.image` in your original code.

Comment: R.drawable.image gives me a drawable, this gives me an integer!

Comment: False!!! R.drawable.image gives you an integer!!! Look at the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable(int,%20android.content.res.Resources.Theme)). `R.drawable.image` retruns the identifier of the image, and the `getDrawable()` function gets the Drawable from the identifier

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the quest completely (the problem you are having is that the method does not return a drawable?

I'm not sure you about how you are getting the context, but you could try this:

```
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat(getContext(), R.drawable.image);
```

If you are storing the context in a variable, you can pass the variable instead of using `getContext()`.

Additionally, the method you are using to get the drawable is deprected, so you shouldn't be using it anymore.

Let me know if it helped you and remember to upvote/select this as correct answer if it did, cheers.